# "String.substring(int, int) line: not available" causes error

Tags: java, substring, bufferedreader

Somehow my if loop using a substring to check a .txt file is causing problems. Without the if loop, everything works fine. But with it, it seems that an empty line in the text file is causing it to crash. It is working until the first empty line in the file, and then I get this error. What could I do about that?

code:

```
public class S1_Blockchain extends ConsoleProgram {

    public void init() {
        setSize(400, 250);
        setFont("Arial-bold-18");

        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line;
        
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("block_chain.txt"));
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                if(line.substring(0,1).equals("T") || line.substring(0,1).equals("G")) {
                   System.out.println(line);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: `line.startsWith("T")` is a better way to check if a string starts with T. It avoids creation of an unnecessary substring, but also handles the emptiness case, and is simply more expressive of the intent.

Comment: No-one seems to have told you what the original problem is.  An empty line has no characters (readline removed the line terminator).  Your substring call is extracting the first character - which does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to also check empty string:

```
if( !line.trim().isEmpty() && (line.substring(0,1).equals("T") || line.substring(0,1).equals("G"))) { ... }
```

You then might also want to refactor the code to make it more readable:

```
public class S1_Blockchain extends ConsoleProgram {

    public void init() {
        setSize(400, 250);
        setFont("Arial-bold-18");

        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line;
        
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("block_chain.txt"));
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                if(shouldConsider(line)) {
                   System.out.println(line);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
    }
}

private boolean shouldConsider(String line){
  return !line.trim().isEmpty() 
         && 
         (line.substring(0,1).equals("T") || line.substring(0,1).equals("G"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you tested your first edge-case for **empty** string `""` (unhappy path).

Next you can avoid *effective empty* cases by using `trim()` (remove surrounding white-spaces):

- so spaced input like `"   Trouble Centered   "` becomes *trimmed* `"Trouble Centered" (so that starting with a "T" which could be wanted).
- and **blank** lines like `"   "` become *empty* string `""` (which will break some tests)

```java
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("block_chain.txt"));
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            line = line.trim(); // remove white-spaces; blank line results as empty
            if (line.isEmpty()) {
              // might handle or ignore this case
            }

            firstChar = line.charAt(0);  // expresses intend better than substring
            if (Set.of('T', 'G').contains(firstChar) { // the Set improves readability for condition
               System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
```

#### Alternatives for Testing Strings

A) separate tests:

- could also test an empty (not even spaces) or blank (only spaces) with `line.isBlank()`
- could also test the start of a string with `line.startsWith("T")`

B) all in one (your case):

- with a *regular expression* catching all cases: `line.matches("^\\s*(G|T)")`

Comment: @idontknowanything Glad, it helped you, maybe the future reader too. Remember: you can [vote on answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Well I tried but obviously I need a reputation of at least 15 to vote...

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks, for pointing out: zero-indexing.

Comment: @k314159 Without IDE I got sloppy with typing. Inspired me to fix and add the regex (hope I escaped the whitespace correctly).

Answer (score -1):

Besides checking if your String is null you also have to check if it is an empty String (""). You can check it as `line.trim().legth() == 0;` or `line.isEmpty()` but also there is Apache Utils called [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html). There there is a method `isBlank(String str)` that checks in one go if String is null or blank. That is what I would recommend

Comment: Java 11 supports this test on String, like `line.isBlank()`. See [isBlank()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#isBlank())